# Minimum User Role Needed to Connect Salesforce Data Cloud (CDP) to Salesforce Marketing Cloud (also disabling)

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforce-cdp, datacloud, cdp

I'm trying to connect Salesforce CDP (Aka Genie, Data Cloud) to Marketing Cloud. I was able to do this as a full administrator in both systems, but I now need to do it with the bare minimum permissions required. There is very, very little documentation out there on any of the auth stuff. Does anyone have experience with this and can share if you're even able to connect with anything less than administrator?

In addition, I had a demo org, tried to disconnect it, but that's failing. Has anyone had any success there?